# How do I accommodate this drain stack in the way of my finishing surfaces?

Tags: tile, bathtub, tiling

I was ready to lay the tile board over the studs above the tub until I noticed (late - I know) that the cast iron stack running up the corner of the wall line is protruding too far. The tile board will not lay flat as the coupler (2 of them) stick out about 1" too far for the boards to meet and lay flat in that corner (see pics).

A plumber suggested trying anything besides tearing out the stack and replacing with less obtrusive PVC (too expensive). He suggested using an angle grinder to grind down the collars of the couplers. I measured and found that I would need to grind beyond the collar into the coupler compromising the stack.

Any thoughts of how to lay the tile board without removing the stack?

[image: Stack running up corner]

[image: Side view of stack and couplers protruding]

Comment: Since things are not set in stone (or tile) can you create a 45 corner there, I think it takes 22” for a standard toilet , move the closet flange and then the toilet could be set at a 45. This is how I have hidden cast pipes where I did not want to shim out or stagger the wall, I liked it so much the last 2 homes and my current one that I remodeled bathrooms I put the throne so you are not looking at the wall or cabinet. If that won’t work you can stagger the wall but this always looked hokey to me.

Comment: Your main choices are to remove or replace the stack(mainly a bad idea), grind down the stack(also a bad idea), or make the studs thicker(or wider) with thin wood stripes to go past the stack.  Last choice will decrease the floor space a bit.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. If I were to add furring strips to the current studs to bring out the tile backer beyond the stack couplers, I'm wondering how to handle the gap between the tile back and the flange on the tub surround. I'm picturing a gap between the backer and the flange (if I take the backer to the tub surround, not the top of the flange). Would I just caulk that space?

Comment: May not work for you, but you could rotate the whole thing a few degrees. If you shim where the pipe is, that wall will probably be what 1 or 2 degrees clockwise. Put tub flush to it, then you need to shim back wall so that board is also 2 degrees clockwise, same with the right wall. You end up with 90 degree inside corners and the whole thing slightly rotated clockwise 2 degrees. This may bug some people though specially if prone to see things like this

Comment: In addition to the cost of replacement, it's my understanding that cast iron pipes are much _quieter_ than PVC plumbing. That means that flushes and sink/shower drains from above won't be heard nearly as loudly in this bathroom as they would if you replaced it with smaller (no hub) PVC piping.

Answer (score 1):

First choice would be to move the tub off the wall enough so you can fir out those studs to get past the piping.

Second choice would be to fir out those studs and leave the tub in place- just bury the tub a bit. The tub flange is for waterproofing- it keeps water from getting into the wall from between the tub and the tile. Typically your cement backer board would go down to the top of that flange and the tile would go over that (and span over the flange with your tile setting compound behind it). Downside of this is that your tub ledge will be smaller.

Last choice (to me) would be getting involved in replacing plumbing pipes, etc.